# How to limit users based on who created a task to edit their own stuff on Share Point using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am wanting to allow people to edit their own task on share point using the edit icon  on the left hand side located on the list. What i dont want is for people to edit other peoples information on someone else tasks .

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible using javascript. User will be able to go to the list url directly create their own view and be able to edit it.

You have 2 options:

A. Use custom permission (using some wf/flow you could trigger it automatically upon creation and  grant only the edit rights) but having list with custom permission has its performance drawbacks.

B. You could use the Item Level Security Feature (and I think it will be better option for you) Go to list settings->Advanced settings and there you can set up Read and Edit access only to the author of the list item (in your case Task)

Comment: I did that for some odd reason it doesn't work. What I am trying to do is when some one makes a task they should be the only one to edit that task. I want no one else to edit someone elses task.

Comment: Then as mentioned option B will be best for you, please remember as site col admin you will be able to see all the tasks.

Comment: i did be option its still enables other people to edit the list.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your tenant. I would suggest raising support ticket with MS.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use custom code or javascript as you can take advantage of OOTB functionality in SharePoint.

According to my understanding you are looking for **Item-Level Permissions**.

Below is a good article on how to enable item level permissions in SharePoint. maybe it will help you with your requirements.

[How to enable Item Level Permissions in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/).